# how to handle change event in jquery?

Tags: jquery

What could be wrong with below function? Theres a

tag in error and it gets filled when error occurs, the error is thus shown for a sec and then disappers.

```
$('#error').hide(); 
$('#error').find('p').change(function(){
    if($(this).contents().length > 0){
        $(this).show();
    }
});
```

EDIT: adding the error piece too

```
<div id="error" class="error">
<span style="float:right" >CLICK to remove.</span>
{% block error %}
    {% ifnotequal '' where %}
    <p>where-{{where}}</p>
    {% endifnotequal %}
    {% if error %}
    <p> error-{{error}}</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
</div>
```

Comment: The error does come for a while and then disappears. The p is created dynamically including its contents. #error div is blank till then.

Comment: Actually, I am not sure what is your question anymore. Could you tell us what is it that you are expecting the code to do?

Comment: If I comment out the hide then it continues to show and change event is not triggered. ie., 
//$("#error").hide();
But then I dont want it be always shown to the user.

Comment: P elements don't trigger onchange events.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, the change event works only for the input elements, it wouldn't fire for your paragraph element.

**EDIT:**
If your problem is that the paragraphs become invisible again, then there must be some other code which does that. Check for setInternal or setTimeout method calls in your code.

Comment: there are none , i have also checked on pages where there are no external js got is getting loaded in end

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question properly, what's wrong with your code is that it's expecting the `onchange` event on a `p` to get called.  This isn't a thing that normally happens.  You should probably read up on `onchange` and compare/contrast it with whatever behavior you're expecting (which I don't really understand).

Comment: Expected behavior is for error div to remain visible when content is added inside it on error.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're setting the `<p>` to be displayed when it is changed. Why would the `<p>` be changing? By the way, the `#error` element is being hidden, so setting the `<p>` to display isn't going to do anything if its parent is hidden. I think you might need an `.end()` in there to revert back to the `#error` element.

I think this is more in line with what you want:

```
$('#error').hide(); 
$('#error').find('p').change(function(){
        if($(this).contents().length > 0){
                $(this).parent().show();    // .parent() should return #error
        }
});
```

Comment: tried both $('#error').find('p').end().change() and $('#error').find('p').andSelf().change(), it shows for a while and then gets hidden.

Comment: That won't work because you're setting the change event to both. Try the code above.

Comment: Even if you assign change event to the #error and the p elements, there is no reason for the elements to 'disappear'. Something else is going on here.

Comment: I end and and self in mutually exclusive state ie., when one one used the other was not,  The disappearing act is continuing with code too

Answer (score 0):

There is no JavaScript error in your code. The issue is that you are hidding the error div. Find is a traversing method that looks to all children of a div. And then you choose to show a div in with a hidden parent. It will not show anything.

Comment: I would have left the problem if it dint show but it's visible for a sec and then goes

Comment: this is probably an internal mecanism of browser redraw. It detects that you call a show but later check the parent and hides again